# retrieve custom listbox items value

Tags: vb.net, windows-phone-7.1

This is how I add the 2 textblock to my listbox as an item

```
Dim StkP As New StackPanel
StkP.Name = "Stack"

Dim txtLine_1 As New TextBlock
txtLine_1.FontSize = 24
txtLine_1.Name = "txtLine_1"
txtLine_1.Text = "Units " + txtUnits_1.Text + ", Cost " + txtCost_1.Text

Dim txtLine_2 As New TextBlock
txtLine_2.FontSize = 24
txtLine_2.Name = "txtLine_2"
txtLine_2.Text = txtResult_1.Text

StkP.Children.Add(txtLine_1)
StkP.Children.Add(txtLine_2)

ListCompare.Items.Add(StkP)
```

But how can I retrieve the selected items values when I tap on listbox in vb.net?

I tried this code

```
Dim lbi As ListBoxItem = ListScore.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(ListScore.SelectedIndex)
Dim stk As StackPanel = lbi.Content
Dim rs_1 As TextBlock = stk.FindName("lblScore_1")
Score_1.Text = rs_1.Text
```

But it is always returning the last input of "lblScore_1"

Any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to:
- take the selected item;
- cast it to a StackPanel;
- access the children of the stackpanel;
- cast the child items to TextBlocks and then read their properties as necessary

Using databinding would make this much easier.

Comment: Hi, I tried this code

    Dim lbi As ListBoxItem = ListScore.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(ListScore.SelectedIndex)
    Dim stk As StackPanel = lbi.Content
    Dim rs_1 As TextBlock = stk.FindName("lblScore_1")
    Score_1.Text = rs_1.Text

But it is always returning the last input of "lblScore_1"

Any help